# Change background colour from one column based on other column's value in Streamlit and Ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, python, ag-grid, streamlit

I am using Ag-Grid with streamlit, currently trying to make the fields of "column A" green coloured when the value from "column B" is “yes”. In other words, elem1 and elem3 should be displayed with green background in the following example:

| Header A | Header B |
| --- | --- |
| elem1 | yes |
| elem2 | no |
| elem3 | yes |

This code is not working, somebody could tell me why? thanks in advance

```
   cellsytle_jscode = JsCode("""
    function(params) {
        if (df['Header B'].value == 'yes') {
            return {
                'color': 'white',
                'backgroundColor': 'green'
            }
        } else {
            return {
                'color': 'black',
                'backgroundColor': 'red'
            }
        }
    };
    """) 
    
    gb.configure_column("Header A", cellStyle=cellsytle_jscode)
```